# How do I create a drop-down list using hover::after?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, mousehover

I'm having trouble in figuring out how to create a vertical drop-down menu since I'm using hover::after in my CSS. I'm trying to have a transparent drop-down list under shops where I created a submenu consisting of best-selling, sales and gifts. But when I write these codes down, the submenu don't seem to appear at all but the hovering effect on "Shop" is still there and I couldn't figure out how to make this work. Sorry if my lines of codes are messy, I'm still learning how to code and develop a website through YouTube.

```css
.navbar {
  height: 12%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
}

nav ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #E6C7F3;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover::after .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SHOP</a></li>
        <div class="submenu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Best-Selling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <li><a href="">FEEDBACK</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children

Comment: Also `li:hover::after .submenu` is not going to work because the submenu is not a child of the pseudo-element

Comment: Is there a way you could demonstrate to me a way to fix this issue?

Comment: The simplest way would be to remove the submenu div wrapper and apply the submenu class to the child `ul`. Then `nav ul li:hover .submenu` will work.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help man! I'll try it out in a bit and update you on my progress